# JNativeHook how do you keep from printing everything that happens?

Tags: java

So I need jnativehook to detect when a copy/paste is preformed as a copy/paste backup application, and since this is a console application I don't want it getting spammed by cursor position and keystrokes, I just need it to sit there quitely and listen for copy/paste. But instead this is happening

```
    Oct 25, 2014 10:21:54 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [405]: Mouse moved to 3468, 829.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:54 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [405]: Mouse moved to 3468, 828.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:54 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [405]: Mouse moved to 3467, 827.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:54 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [405]: Mouse moved to 3467, 826.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:54 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [405]: Mouse moved to 3467, 825.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:55 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_get_multi_click_time [218]: XtGetMultiClickTime: 200.

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:55 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [290]: Button 1  pressed 1 time(s). (3467, 825)

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:55 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [358]: Button 1 released 1 time(s). (3467, 825)

Oct 25, 2014 10:21:55 AM org.jnativehook
INFO: hook_event_proc [372]: Button 1 clicked 1 time(s). (3467, 825)
```

Is there a way to turn that off? I have the basic Native Hook registration and error catching as well as the three empty listening events.

```
try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException n) {

            System.err.println("JNativeHook could not be registered");
            System.err.println(n.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new Main());
```

Answer (score 13):

From the usage wiki on the JNativeHook github.

```java
// Clear previous logging configurations.
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();

// Get the logger for "org.jnativehook" and set the level to off.
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Adding these lines of code to your main object's constructor, for example, would keep the almost all logging from being displayed in your console.  This however, only applies to JNativeHook version 1.2 (newest).

There is also an option to only display warnings and errors as well.

Comment: FWIW here's the above code in Kotlin.

`// Clear previous logging configurations.`
`LogManager.getLogManager().reset()`
`// Get the logger for "org.jnativehook" and set the level to off.`
`val logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen::class.java.\`package\`.name)`
`logger.level = Level.OFF`

Answer (score 4):

... by reading the [documentation](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage#logging-and-console-output).  JNativeHook uses java.util.logging for console output.  Note that you cannot disable to copyright via the logger by design.

Comment: At first: Thanks for your lib, it's great! (But I oversaw the documentation as well - maybe you can reference to it more explicit :))

Comment: Yah, I really need to redo the Wiki pages.  Its on my TODO list along with 2.0.3.  PS the copyright text has also been removed from 2.0.3.

Comment: Thanks for reply, thats nice, I found your (older) docs on Google Archive, with them I finally get my little clipboard-manager working. :) Btw: it's running in JavaFX 2.0. The deployment / compiling was a little tricky - using maven didn't ship an exe / jar - but by moving your lib into the "extracted output dir" (can be setup in artifact config in IntelliJ), everything is working as a charm. So thanks a lot for this masterpiece! Can highly recommend your work. :) Do you have any advice for me how to get some introduction in "jni" and native programming? I want to get more familiar with it.

Comment: Please file a bug report on GitHub about the maven and Java FX stuff.  There is already a report about some maven InteliJ issues [here](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues/65).  I don't really use maven for anything so if something is broken I would never know.  It should be shipping a JAR with binaries included in it.  If you need JNI help, just shoot me an email.